# STM32 UART not transmitting data

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm using B-L4S5I-IOT01A board and I'm not able to make UART working properly. It's working fine when using HAL, but when I'm trying to operate directly on registers there is no data transferred to my PC (at least I can't see in terminal).

```
#include "stm32l4r5xx.h"

#define SYS_FREQ 8000000
#define UART_BAUDRATE 115200
#define TXE 1U << 7

void write_uart(int value) {
  while (!(USART1->ISR & TXE)) {}
  USART1->TDR = (value & 0xFF);
}

int main() 
{
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1U << 1;
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1U << 2;
  
  // PIN UART TX
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1U << 0;

  GPIOA->MODER &= ~(1U << 18);
  GPIOA->MODER |= 1U << 19;
  
  GPIOA->AFR[1] |= 1U << 4;
  GPIOA->AFR[1] |= 1U << 5;
  GPIOA->AFR[1] |= 1U << 6;
  GPIOA->AFR[1] &= ~(1U << 7);

  // UART
  RCC->APB1ENR1 |= 1U << 17;
  RCC->APB2ENR |= 1U << 14;

  USART1->CR1 &= ~(1U << 15);
  USART1->BRR = (SYS_FREQ / UART_BAUDRATE);

  USART1->CR1 |= 1U << 0;
  USART1->CR1 |= 1U << 3;

  while (1)
  {
    write_uart('Y');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide adequate amount of information. 1) Full name of the MCU 2) Full description of what peripherals are used with what pins 3) What you attempted to solve it, whether you tried checking things with debugger, noticed some config missing. 4) What's the state of UART lines? Are they permanently high? Permanently low? Is there any traffic on them? 5) Add comments to every 1-2 lines about what exactly they do, I can't remember what bit number 15 of the control register of this specific MCU does. Please, make answering your question a little easier in general.

Comment: Also, why are you activating GPIOB and GPIOC, if you only use GPIOA for USART? Why do you provide clock to USART1 AND USART2? Are you sure you have correct BRR? After all, USART1 is clocked from APB2. Compare register content of your configuration vs after HAL setup. There has to be some difference.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use magic numbers. Use human-readable definitions from the STM CMSIS headers. I am not going to decode bit numbers as it makes no sense and it is very easy to make a stupid mistake.
2. Read the Reference Manual. After enabling a peripheral clock you need to make sure that that it has propagated through the bus. You can read back, execute the barrier instruction or add a small delay.
   4.TXE - you got a warning there - read it and correct.

```
GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE6_1;
```

It is no-op in your uC. It is by default in analog mode and has to be reset before setting.

```
GPIOB->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE6_MSK;
GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE6_1;
```

You also do not need a long delay (3 clocks are needed). Readback is the best option as operations on the bus are strongly ordered.

```
RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOBEN;
(void)RCC->AHB2ENR;
```